# What will happen if I multiply a ket vector by a complex number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, complex-numbers, quantum-states

I was reading Zettili’s *Quantum Mechanics* book. There I have seen

> when a ket (or bra) multiplied by complex number, we also get a ket (or bra)

But how do we infer this by mathematics?

Comment: You correctly called the kets vectors. Are you confused by the fact that these vectors can be multiplied by complex numbers and not just by real numbers?

Comment: no no i havent any problem with this .anywho can multiply with this number(real or complex) associated to ket but how can i get back that state same as previous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The states of a quantum system, the kets, are elements of a [*complex* Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) (modulo a phase). A complex Hilbert space is nothing more than a fancy (in)finite dimensional [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) equipped with an inner product. So being the Hilbert space a vector space, all the rules which define a vector space apply. The field upon which the vector space is constructed is the one of complex numbers and so to every vector $|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ there is another vector $c|\psi\rangle\in\mathcal{H}$ where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ since in vector spaces we can multiply any element by an element of the underlying field, which in this case is the complex numbers.

Comment: ok!so u meant to prove that is closer property in vector space and u are telling, c|ψ⟩∈H is belonging to the set of hilbert space.after multipling we also get another ket vector in scaling form(some complex constant multiplied).that story,is this book wants to render?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, notice that you are asking "But how do we infer this by mathematics?". However, you don't infer or "prove" it, it's just how QM is constructed (there is motivation for that, i.e. there is a physical guidance leading to this Hilbert space construction... but it's not a "mathematical proof").

Comment: A Hilbert space is a bit more than a vector space with an inner product. It also most be complete: if you have a sequence of nested closed spheres, there must be a point that is in all of them.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yeah, I know! I made it a little bit easier, hiding all the precise stuff under the word *fancy*, just so that the important property for which the question was asked were answered.

Comment: True, but such small inaccuracies are a real burr to us pendantics.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ahah! That's true, I'm sorry to whoever I'll bother in the future with this answer

Answer (score 4):

Think about this like that,- when you multiply a vector by a scalar, you just re-scale original vector. Same idea applies here to vectors in Hilbert space, aka. ket. You just re-scale Hilbert vector by a complex number, an hence get another ket in same Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0):

Two things happen, depending on the magnitude and phase of the complex factor. Both can be seen by examining what happens when you insert the factor $f$ in $\mid\Psi\rangle = f\mid\psi\rangle$.

Your primary observables are always bra-ket pairs, so calculate $\langle\Psi\mid\Psi\rangle=\langle\psi\mid f^*f\mid\psi\rangle = |f|^2\langle\psi\mid\psi\rangle$. ($f^*$ is applied to the bra, since it's the complex conjugate of the ket.) That is, multiplying a state by a complex value multiplies the *number* of particles by the square of the $f$'s magnitude. The phase of $f$ can only be observed via interference with the original $\mid\psi\rangle$, since phase is generally unobservable.

Since operators like mass and momentum are linear, increasing the number increases mass & momentum proportionately. If there are self-interactions in the energy or other operators, those can change in non-linear fashion.

Comment: MathJax tip: you can format bra-ket notation using `\langle`, `\mid` and `\rangle` (e.g $\langle\Psi\mid\Psi\rangle$)